# Changing the font size of horizontal category axis in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to change the font size of Horizontal category axis in a line chart.

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.add_series({
        'name': f'Chart Title',
        'categories': "=Sheet!$B$1:$B$10",
        'values': "= Sheet!$C$1:$C$10",
        'y_axis': True, 'x_axis': True,
        'data_labels': {'value': True, 'position': 'above', 'num_format': '0%',
                        'font': {'color': 'black', 'size': 10}}})
```

I am however unsure how to change the font size of the category labels or values in the x-axis of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I had to do the below to get the desired output

```
chart.set_x_axis({'num_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': False}})
```